# Hissing noise produced by disk access

Tags: audio, ssd, speakers, noise, nvme

On my MSI B360-A each disk access (NVME and SATA-SSD) produces clearliy audible interference in my speakers.

It doesn't matter which kind of connection I'm using to transport audio, whenever there's disk access it's accompanied by scratching, hissing noise in the speakers.

What baffles me the most is the fact, that the interference is reproduced via USB ports. So I'm guessing it's not just a simple ground loop, right?

Any ideas what might by causing this and how to eliminate it?

---

Troubleshooting I've done so far:

- Using USB-Audio device on back / front USB ports
- Using a different set of speakers
- Disconnecting / switching off all devices (even keyboard, mouse)
- Switching to different power outlets for PC and speakers

Edit:
Forgot to mention that using the USB-Audio device on my monitor's USB hub or it's HDMI output eliminates the noise, so I'm pretty confident it's caused by the PC.

Edit 2:
Connection via 3.5mm (front, back analog audio out and USB-Audio) to cinch line in at speakers. No noise via unpowered headphones.

Comment: This is probably caused by poor shielding on the motherboard.  I myself have experienced this even on the highest end motherboard.  I too (like you) am surprised to hear that it even happens with USB sound sources.  Sounds stupid.. but have you tried a Linux live boot to see if it happens there?  Might help you whittle down where the problem really is.

Comment: You forgot to mention what kind of speakers you have. As per the description, they are mains-powered amplified speakers, with 3.5mm analog connection to PC? Have you tried with another set of speakers, or even simply with headphones?

Comment: Note: ground loops don't cause 'hiss' [white noise], they cause 'hum' [deeper sound] at the frequency of your mains, 50 or 60 Hz, plus overtones [harmonic & inharmonic]. Rule of thumb:- if a sound has a "note" of any kind & is not a ground loop, then it's RFI [radio frequency interference]. In computers this is usually cheap components & poor shielding.

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas I'm mainly using Linux, which boots from the NVME. I tried booting from the Windows SATA-SSD (no access to NVME because Windows doesn't understand btrfs at all). Both OS experience the same problems.

Comment: @Justme Edifier speakers, powered. I have access to other powered monitors and also tried with headphones. You mentioning headphones just made me find out: I doesn't happen with non-powered devices (headphones front/back connector, USB device).

Comment: @Tetsujin Right, I was aware of how a ground loop sounds. I'm just lacking the term for "interference caused signals traveling over common ground wires". Sorry, no RF technician here ;).

Comment: The RF is picked up somewhere in the audio path by poorly-shielded or cheap components, exactly like a radio station in a radio receiver. That then goes onward 'down the wire' until it eventually reaches an amplifier which brings it up [along with desired signals] to audible levels. Using a separate USB interface ought to eliminate that RF, or more accurately, just not pick it up in the first place.

Comment: @Tetsujin A separate USB interface (any, in fact, tried a few) still transported the signal if attached directly to the PC. So my guess is that the PC adds it to all digital signal paths - maybe on USB VCC/GND?

Comment: It could potentially be leaking to the common ground rail, yes. Then it's picked up again by anything else directly attached. Is the computer itself properly earthed, & the mobo & all peripherals correctly connected to that? I'm so used to being in a country where earthing is compulsory I forget there are many where it isn't.

Comment: Europe/Austria, building from 2012 here, so I do hope it's properly grounded. At least last time I accidentally hit ground with a switched-off phase (ceiling lights) the breaker tripped. Just did a successful continuity test from power cable's earth to DVI socket and mainboard's back plane. This should mean the PC is built correctly, right?

Comment: It would suggest so, yes. I think we're back to poor shielding on the mobo, but tbh I'm out of ideas :/